# XmlDocument XML generation

Tags: xml, attributes, xmldocument

I'm trying to write an XML file that look similar to below.  But I'm having a really hard time using XmlDocument.  I was able to create the first part but I'm struggling to generate the ACABusinessHeader's block.  I'm not able to add the acaBusHeader prefix.  I tried adding manifestBusHeader.Prefix but that yielded no results.

What I'm trying to create:

```
<p:ACAUIBusinessHeader xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"         
xmlns="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0" 
xmlns:acaBusHeader="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheader" 
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-
wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:irs="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common" 
xmlns:p="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acauibusinessheader" 
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acauibusinessheader IRS-
ACAUserInterfaceHeaderMessage.xsd">

<acaBusHeader:ACABusinessHeader>
</acaBusHeader:ACABusinessHeader>
```

This is my code:

```
var topLevel = xdoc.CreateElement("p", "ACAUIBusinessHeader", "urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acauibusinessheader");
var schemaLocation = xdoc.CreateAttribute("xsi", "schemaLocation", "urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acauibusinessheader");
schemaLocation.Value = "urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acauibusinessheader IRS-ACAUserInterfaceHeaderMessage.xsd";
topLevel.SetAttributeNode(schemaLocation);

topLevel.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", @"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
topLevel.SetAttribute("xmlns", "urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:ext:aca:air:7.0");
topLevel.SetAttribute("xmlns:acaBusHeader", "urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:msg:acabusinessheader");
topLevel.SetAttribute("xmlns:wsu", @"http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
topLevel.SetAttribute("xmlns:irs", "urn:us:gov:treasury:irs:common");

var manifestBusHeader = xdoc.CreateElement("acaBusHeader", "ACABusinessHeader", "");
```

Thanks

Comment: I find it easier just to create a string with the xml and then parse the string to an element.

Comment: @jdweng I thought about going that route.  I have invested too much time into this problem so I want to know the solution. lul